# What are these white spots on my solar panel

Tags: diodes, solar-cell, manufacturing

I purchased a [5W solar panel from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9241), and after using it outside for about a week, these large white spots started showing up.

[image: White spots on solar panel]

Here's a closeup:
[image]

The solar panel is not being back-fed thanks to an inline diode blocking any reverse current.

What is causing these white spots to form.  Is the panel overheating when connected to the load?  Is this a manufacturing defect?

Comment: They look like bubbles caused by delamination of the panel.

Comment: That would be my guess as well, can you push carefully on the glass and see if the bubble (temporarily) goes away or moves?

Comment: The white spots definitely bulge out, but pushing on them doesn't make them move.

Comment: I'd talk to SparkFun about this. This definitely shouldn't happen.

Comment: I agree: I've never see this before, but it could have been doing something wrong.

Comment: Why is this question getting a downvote? I'd be more than happy to address the issue if there is one.

Comment: You get what you pay for. Hooray for Sparkfun (not)

Comment: At $50 each, I'd expect that they don't do this.  Unless of course $50 is cheap and I should be paying a lot more?  Do you know were I could get a higher quality panel of similar power and dimensions?

Comment: The web page mentions hard board backing. To me this is not suitable for use outdoors use without further sealing as it absorbs moisture..

Comment: This is a very interesting point.  I checked and the epoxy coating does not extend all the way to the back of the panel, as you suggested.  Since the panel is horizontal with a small air gap, moisture most certainly makes its way into the panel through the hard board backing.  This means I have to find another solar panel as buying a new one from Sparkfun will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea, but I found this picture of PV cell delamination from a [now-defunct website](https://www.europe-solar.de/catalog/index.php?main_page=page&id=44). I think it looks a little bit similar to your case, so it might be delamination of the cell. But you compare the picture to yours and be the judge if it seems similar or not.

If it is indeed delamination, then that is a manufacturing defect.

[image: https://www.europe-solar.de/catalog/index.php?main_page=page&id=44]

PS. If the website comes up again, this picture should probably be linked to the original page instead of being re-uploaded here.

Comment: I have yet to find a picture similar to my situation, but I would have to agree that it's most likely delamination.  Interesting side note: apparently delamination gets accelerated with damp-heat cycling, like hot sun right after an intense rainfall: http://www.fsec.ucf.edu/en/publications/pdf/FSEC-PF-426-01.pdf

Comment: Confirmed to be manufacturing defect.